# How to Update a dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to give the user to option to add an item to a dropdownlist.  I have tried implementing a couple of different solutions, but haven't been able to get the added item to appear in the list.

Currently, I am adding the item to the table and then recalling the HttpGet method to recreate the selectlist.  The correct SelectList is created and sent to the View.

Controller:

```
Names= db.Contacts.ToList()
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Contact.ContactID,new SelectList(Model.Names.ToList(), "ContactID", "Name"), "")
```

The correct SelectList is being passed from the Controller to the View (i.e. the added item is included in the list) and when I step through the code, the View contains the correct list.
However, the View is not being re-rendered.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Alternatively you want to populate Contact list server side as well right? Have you checked that at server side it is populating?

Comment: Yes, the list is updated server side, I've also checked that it is passed from Controller to View.

Comment: Have you checked it on View by debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery to insert an item in your SelectList to avoid re-rendering the view. The logic will be then written in JavaScript, with an approach similar to the following:

Assuming your SelectList has the id `selectList`

```
$('#selectList').append('<option value=' + value +'>'+caption+'</option>');
```

Of course, this only takes care of the view, to be able to pass a new value, with its caption in the SelectList. it will not add the Name in the DB, server side.